# Need program to search through an entire text file

Tags: c++, file, text

Bit of a long post, but I'm having difficulty trying to make this program read through the entirety of a text file instead of what it seems like just the first line.

```
// return true only if the code is valid
bool PriceList::isValid(string code) const {
    ifstream myfile;
    string line;
    myfile.open("pricelist.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(myfile,line))
        {
            if (line.find(code) != string::npos)
            {
                cout << line <<endl;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << line <<endl;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        throw invalid_argument("Could not open file");
}
```

The goal of this part of this program is to determine whether a product bar-code in a text file exists or not. Here is part of the text file (pricelist.txt) that was given to us (categories from left to right are name, barcode, price and taxable):

```
Soda_can    1035851680  2.29    1
Red_Cabbage 1163115674  1.99    0
Tomato_Sauce    1195034963  0.29    0
Tuna_chunky_in_water    1304271912  0.59    0
Salad_Dressing  1352230364  1.39    0
```

Here is the code snippet of the main class that tests this function. The addEntry lines calls the addEntry function I already coded to add each item to the end of the text file (we are mainly focusing on the bar-code data values i.e. 1000, 2000). The testAnswer lines calls a function to state whether or not the function is running properly. The first data value is the title of the test, the second is the variable to be tested and the third is the value the function should result in. So for example the first testAnswer line is testing whether or not the barcode 1000 is in the text file and the result is suppose to be true:

```
    { PriceList priceList;
    priceList.addEntry("Apples", "1000", 1.99, false);
    priceList.addEntry("Bananas", "2000", 0.99, false);
    testAnswer("PriceList isValid1", priceList.isValid("1000"), true);
    testAnswer("PriceList isValid2", priceList.isValid("19"), false); }
```

So as I've said I am having trouble making the program read all of the text file. It only seems to be reading the first line, the Soda_can one and it causes both testAnswer functions to result in false. Here is the current output:

```
Soda_can        1035851680      2.29    1
FAILED PriceList isValid1: expected 1 but received 0
Soda_can        1035851680      2.29    1
PASSED PriceList isValid2: expected and received 0
```

If I manually put the Apples and Bananas data values at the very top it results in correct values but obviously I want to make it work for any item anywhere on the text file. I've spent hours trying to solve this and this is the best I've got right now. I'd greatly appreciate any help in this and I thank you for reading all of this if you have. Let me know if any of my explanations are unclear.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  What does `addEntry` have to do with trying to read a file in its entirety?  Either you read the entire file ok or you didn't.  If you did, then the issue has nothing to do with reading a file.

Comment: You return after reading the first line. Move the return false outside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `while` clause you are calling return in both the `if` and `else` sections. This will end processing completely for the function. There is no way for the while clause to reach the second iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that your program returns irrespective of result of code checking `if (line.find(code) != string::npos)`.

Probably, you would like to continue search/reading through file if code is not found and stop reading file once code is found. This should continue till `EOF` is reached.

You can use an additional variable like `bFound` to store result and return it. Like in code below:

```
    bool bFound = false;
    while (getline(myfile,line))
    {
        if (line.find(code) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << line <<endl;
            bFound = true; 
            break;    //Record found break from loop
        }
        else
        {
            cout << line <<endl;
            continue;    //Record not found. Continue loop.
        }
    }
    return bFound;
```

Comment: The `continue` serves no purpose, there's no code after it to skip.